# SQL-Server: set all rows (values) of some selected columns = NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to set all values of some columns (not all)  of a table in an **SQL-Server** database **to NULL**. The problem is, that the table has **more than 30.000.000 rows** and it takes a very long time to update all columns/rows.
How can I speed up the follwoing update statement?

```
Update Table
Set
column1 = null,
column4 = null,
column8 = null,
column12 = null
```

It is not possible to drop the table!

Comment: Is it possible for you just select the not null values into a new table? Can you show us the table schema... please..

Comment: TRUNCATE TABLE thetable;

Comment: @silly "I want to set all values of some columns". And you wanna truncate ?

Comment: Ok so now we tell you to get a faster server. Sorry, no alternative. If you NEED to update 30 million rows (something that should only take a small number of minutes anyway on a decent server) then this is all you can do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the columns are at the end of the table, or if the order of the columns is not relevant, I think the fastest way would be to just drop the column and recreate them again

```
-- assumes no constraints defined on the columns
alter table MyTable
  drop column Column1, Column2, ... 

alter table MyTable
  add column Column1 int null, Column2 varchar(max) null, ...
```

Additionally if the updates are slow in general, it might be a case of over-indexing. Take a look at the indexes that are defined on the table, how many of them there are, what columns are they referencing, etc. In general, inserts and updates get slower with any index defined. However, selects can get much faster, so do not just go in and ax all indexes, but try to locate any indexes that are seldom or never used.

And last, if the database is properly indexed and still too slow, take a look at TomTom's answer.

Edit:

To address the comment about column ordering in SQL Server tables, in most cases it's **totally unimportant**, however there are few scenarios where it must be maintained:

- Some Schema Compare tools do consider the order important, and might report a change in database structure
- The DBA is a major nitpicker (and I am), and will chew your head off if the `ModifiedBy` and `ModifiedOn` columns are not the last two columns in the table

Comment: Nice idea. Columns end of the table is irrelevant btw., because unless some very inexperienced person wrote the sql, the column order is of no relevance. Index participation may be. Not sure about the performance of that though, but you may get around the logging.

Comment: @TomTom: edited to stress that column ordering does not have to, but can be important :)

Answer (score 6):

> The problem is, that the table has more than 30.000.000 rows and it
>   takes a very long time to update all columns/rows. How can I speed up
>   the following update statement?

You buy a faster server.

Seriously.

Unable to drop table. Must update 30 million rows in one statement.

That are both the sides that are unchangeable. There is not a lot of optimization possible (you could kill any index on that fields then recreate them). What is left is getting better hardware.

Sorry, there is no better answer. You could try doing updates 10000 at a time, in a loop - that would make the transactions and statements faster, but i doubt it would make the whole operation faster, which your question is about. At the end the work must be done, and if it needs to be done faster, then you need more power = a faster server.

Comment: +1 *buy a faster server*, *unable to drop, must update 30mil in one statement* :D

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that could help is to disable all indexes used on those fields before running the update, and then rebuilding them afterwards.  This will eliminate some of the I/O overhead.

A second option is to select all of the data from your table into a new table, with the nulls replacing the columns as needed.  Then, truncate the first table, enable identity insert, and select everything from the new table back into the first one.  This would also benefit from the disabling of indexes.

Answer (score 1):

An UPDATE without WHERE tries to update all rows, even those that already have a NULL in the columns. A seemingly pointless filter like the one belong can have a **BIG** impact.

```
UPDATE Table
SET
    column1 = null,
    column4 = null,
    column8 = null,
    column12 = null
WHERE
    column1 IS NOT NULL    OR    
    column4 IS NOT NULL    OR     
    column8 IS NOT NULL    OR    
    column12
```

Or, probably better, depending on distribution:

```
UPDATE Table    SET    column1 = NULL WHERE    column1 IS NOT NULL     
UPDATE Table    SET    column2 = NULL WHERE    column2 IS NOT NULL     
UPDATE Table    SET    column4 = NULL WHERE    column4 IS NOT NULL     
UPDATE Table    SET    column8 = NULL WHERE    column8 IS NOT NULL     
UPDATE Table    SET    column12 = NULL WHERE    column12 IS NOT NULL
```

If it still takes way too long time, try using top (10000) on either solution and repeat until done.

```
UPDATE top (10000) Table    SET    column1 = NULL WHERE    column1 IS NOT NULL 
etc...
```